# Change \printsolutions header string in xsim

Tags: hebrew, xsim

I am using `xsim` to type exercise-solution environments in my document.

I want to change the string used for the header in `\printsolutions[headings=true]`.

The document language is Hebrew, so I want it to be written in that language. Moreover, the solutions should appear at the end of the chapter, and so I want it to read "Solutions to the exercises in chapter `\thechapter`":

> \thechapter פתרונות לתרגילים בפרק

I am new to the `xsim` package (and its manual), and I couldn't find an answer for that in the manual.

A MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print = false,}
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name={תרגיל},
  exercises/name={תרגילים},
  solution/name={פתרון},
  solutions/name={פתרונות},
  exercise/within = chapter,
}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\begin{document}
\chapter{גיאומטריה}
\section{הקדמה}
\begin{exercise}[subtitle={משפט פיתגורס}]
הוכח שסכום שטחי הריבועים, הבנויים על הניצבים במשולש ישר זווית, שווה לשטח הריבוע הבנוי על היתר.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
מוכיחים בקלות.
\end{solution}
\printsolutions[headings=true]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z Could you help me out with [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/type-hint-and-solution-page-references-to-an-exercise-in-the-margin-paragraph-us) I have which is related to this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a translation for the `default-heading` in Hebrew:

```
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{default-heading}{
  Hebrew = פתרונות לתרגילים בפרק \thechapter 
}
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
% arara: xelatex: { interaction: nonstopmode }
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print = false,}
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name={תרגיל},
  exercises/name={תרגילים},
  solution/name={פתרון},
  solutions/name={פתרונות},
  exercise/within = chapter,
}
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{default-heading}{
  Hebrew = פתרונות לתרגילים בפרק \thechapter
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}

\chapter{גיאומטריה}

\section{הקדמה}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle={משפט פיתגורס}]
הוכח שסכום שטחי הריבועים, הבנויים על הניצבים במשולש ישר זווית, שווה לשטח הריבוע הבנוי על היתר.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
מוכיחים בקלות.
\end{solution}

\printsolutions[headings=true]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! As the developer and creator of this package, I would like to have a chat talk with you about the syntax of the package. Is that possible?

Comment: +1: One more answer and you have 1,000 answers!

Comment: @cgnieder I have [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/type-hint-and-solution-page-references-to-an-exercise-in-the-margin-paragraph-us) about xsim that I need help me with. Could you have a look at it?

Answer (score 4):

Changes I made:

```tex
% in preamble: declare a new heading template
\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{solution}{%
    \section*{פתרונות לתרגילים בפרק \thechapter}%
}

% apply that template for \printsolutions
\printsolutions[headings=true,headings-template=solution]
```

Full example:

```tex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print = false,}
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name={תרגיל},
  exercises/name={תרגילים},
  solution/name={פתרון},
  solutions/name={פתרונות},
  exercise/within = chapter,
}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{solution}{%
    \section*{פתרונות לתרגילים בפרק \thechapter}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{גיאומטריה}
\section{הקדמה}
\begin{exercise}[subtitle={משפט פיתגורס}]
הוכח שסכום שטחי הריבועים, הבנויים על הניצבים במשולש ישר זווית, שווה לשטח הריבוע הבנוי על היתר.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
מוכיחים בקלות.
\end{solution}

\printsolutions[headings=true,headings-template=solution]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have some other xsim related questions. Do you mind if we talk about it in the chat?

Comment: @tush Or you can post them as separate questions then not only me on this site can see and help.

Comment: It is just that the waiting time for a comment or an answer could be days.. I particularly need help with the syntax of this package.

Comment: For example, I want to introduce hints to the exercise (hints will be printed at the end of the chapter too), and print a page reference on the margins, adjacent to the exercise, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDJDs.png)

Comment: @tush For hints printed at the end of each chapter, check Example 11: Give hints in `xsim`'s package manual. For references on the margins, one option is to new exercise templates by `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate`, and use `\margin` to add margins.